# Openlayers examples / tutorials / books to create maps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, openlayers, openstreetmap

I am working on a Rails app that has some Geo data and would like to add some mapping functionality.

I would also like to add the ability to draw polygons / polylines and store them in a model for future reference and editing etc.  basically I want the user to be able to drop an associated marker on a map linked to a location or draw a path and alth link that to a another model.

Is the a good site / tutorial / book on this?

Comment: [StackOverflow is not a link farm or search engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128549). Questions that just ask for links to other sites are not appropriate here.

Comment: Sorry for the offense but I am not trying to generate a link farm.  I am resorting to SO because I seem to be unable to find such a resource via the usual sources (i.e. a search engine).

Comment: Asking for "links to sites / tutorials / book" is using StackOverflow as a search engine. This is not the place to ask for referrals to other locations. Questions asked here should be able to be answered here; that's the whole purpose of StackOverflow in the first place. Please read the link I posted, and the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), both of which define clearly what is (and is not) proper to ask here. (While you're at the first link, you should also see the article there about StackOverflow not being a catch-all for questions you can't find a better place for, too.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found OpenLayers 2.10 Beginner's Guide by Erik Hazzard.  Great book.